# writing a command in a file

Tags: bash

I'm having a difficulty writing a command in a file using a bash script (NOT the output of the command + I don't want the command to be executed)
I want the file to simply have `run $(python -c "print('A'*256)")` inside of it.

I've tried adding it in a variable then passing it to a file by echo, that didn't work.

I also tried something like `echo "run $(python -c "print('A'*256)")" > file.txt`

Also didn't work, I actually got some errors so I assumed that the problem is because of the multiple double quotations, so I changed them to single quotations. That gave me this output in the file run

So it basically ignored `$(python -c "print('A'*256)")` completely.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to get arbitrary strings into redirections is to [use a here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

```
cat > file.txt <<'EOT'
run $(python -c "print('A'*256)")
EOT
```

This will put that single line exactly as-is into `file.txt`. The text up until `EOT` is given to `cat` as its standard input, and `cat` just spits it out again to be redirected. The shell will keep reading the document until `EOT` appears at the start of the line, so you could put multiple lines in at once if you wanted (if `EOT` appears like that within your string, use something else instead - the delimiter is arbitrary).

Because the delimiter is quoted at the top, no expansions are performed on the body of the here-document<sup>1</sup> and all your characters are passed through untouched. [The behaviour of here-documents is specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) and will work in any shell.

<sup>1</sup><sub>[There was a bug in some older versions of Bash that did perform some expansions in certain cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340923/what-does-posix-require-for-quoted-here-documents-inside-command-substitution), but you won't hit that here.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A string with ***both kinds** of quotes in it is always hard to handle. 
There are three approaches:

- Alternate between the two kinds of quotes. 
  Put the double quotes (`"`) inside single quotes (`'`) and vice versa.

  First break your string into three pieces:

  ```
  run $(python -c "print ('A'*256) ")
  ↑---------1----------↑ ↑---2---↑ ↑3↑
  ```

  where the first and third part contain no single quotes,
  and the second part has no double quotes. 
  Then quote them appropriately:

  ```
  echo 'run $(python -c "print'"('A'*256)"'")'
       ↑----------1-----------↑↑----2----↑↑-3↑
  ```

  just running the substrings together.
- Quote the string with double quotes,
  and then use `\"` for every literal double quote
  that you want to have echoed. 
  Also replace `$` with `\$`

  ```
  echo "run \$(python -c \"print('A'*256)\")"
  ```
- An approach that works in bash only is to quote the string with `$'…'`. 
  Inside such a string, you can escape single quotes with `\'`:

  ```
  echo $'run $(python -c "print(\'A\'*256)")'
  ```

Of course the `> file.txt` part is as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use escape characters instead:

`echo run \$\(python -c \"print\(\'A\'*256\)\"\) > file.txt`

Comment: IMHO, this is ugly and hard to get right (easy to get wrong).   But it *does* work, unlike the other answer.