# How are double quotation marks in bash matched (paired)?

Tags: bash, quoting, wildcards

I am using `GNU bash` `4.3.48`. Consider the following two commands that only differ by a single dollar sign.

Command 1:

```
echo "(echo " * ")"
```

Command 2:

```bash
echo "$(echo " * ")"
```

The output of them are, respectively

```
(echo  test.txt ppcg.sh )
```

and

```
 *
```

So obviously in the first case the `*` is globbed, which means that the first quotation mark goes with the second to form a pair, and the third and the fourth form another pair.

In the second case the `*` is not globbed, and there are exactly two extra spaces in the output, one before the asterisk and one after, meaning that the second quotation mark goes with the third one, and the first goes with the fourth.

Are there any other cases besides the `$()` construction that the quotation marks are not matched with the next one, but are nested instead? Is this behavior well documented and if yes, where can I find the corresponding document?

Comment: Related: [Bash quotes unescaped on command substitution](https://superuser.com/q/909764/354511).

Comment: Once again, the syntax highlight in UL SE is wrong and misleading, though prettify JS is the one to blame.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any of the nesting constructs that can be interpolated inside strings can have further strings inside them: they are parsed like a new script, up to the closing marker, and can even be nested multiple levels deep. All bar one of those starts with a `$`. All of them are documented in a combination of the Bash manual and POSIX shell command language specification.

There are a few cases of these constructs:

- [Command substitution with `$( ... )`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution), as you've found. [POSIX specifies this behaviour](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

  > With the `$(command)` form, all characters following the open parenthesis to the matching closing parenthesis constitute the command. Any valid shell script can be used for *command* ...

  Quotes are part of valid shell scripts, so they're allowed with their normal meaning.
- Command substitution using `` ` ``, too.
- The "word" element of [advanced parameter substitution instances such as `${parameter:-word}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). The [definition of "word" is](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions):

  > A sequence of characters treated as a unit by the shell

  - which includes quoted text and even mixed quotes `a"b"c'd'e` - though the actual behaviour of the expansions is a little more liberal than that, and for example `${x:-hello world}` works too.
- [Arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) with `$(( ... ))`, although it is largely useless there (but you can nest command substitution or variable expansions, too, and then have quotes usefully inside those). [POSIX states that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04):

  > The expression shall be treated as if it were in double-quotes, except that a double-quote inside the expression is not treated specially. The shell shall expand all tokens in the expression for parameter expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.

  so this behaviour is explicitly required. That means `echo "abc $((4 "*" 5))"` does arithmetic, rather than globbing.

  Note though that old-style `$[ ... ]` arithmetic expansion is *not* treated the same way: quotes will be an error if they appear, regardless of if the expansion is quoted or not. This form isn't documented at all any more, and isn't meant to be used anyway.
- [Locale-specific translation with `$"..."`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Locale-Translation), which actually uses the `"` as a core element. `$"` is treated as a single unit.

There's one further nesting case you may not expect, not involving quotes, which is with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion): `{a,b{c,d},e}` expands to "a bc bd e". `${x:-a{b,c}d}` does *not* nest, however; it is treated as a parameter substitution giving "`a{b,c`", followed by "`d}`". That [is also documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> When braces are used, the matching ending brace is the first ‘}’ not escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an embedded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter expansion.

---

As a general rule, all delimited constructs parse their bodies independently of the surrounding context (and [exceptions are treated as bugs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340923/what-does-posix-require-for-quoted-here-documents-inside-command-substitution)). In essence, on seeing `$(` the command-substitution code just asks the parser to consume what it can from the body as though it's a new program, and then checks that the expected terminating marker (an unescaped `)` or `))` or `}`) appears once the sub-parser runs out of things it can consume.

If you think about the functioning of a [recursive-descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), that's just a simple recursion to the base case. It's actually easier to do than the other way, once you've got string interpolation at all. Regardless of the underlying parsing technique, shells supporting these constructs give the same result.

You can nest quoting as deeply as you like through these constructs and it will work as expected. Nowhere will get confused by seeing a quote in the middle; instead, that will be the start of a new quoted string in the interior context.

Comment: Thanks. In [`"blah/blah\n$(cat "${tmpdir}/${filename}.jpdf")"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421740/should-i-double-quote-these-parameter-expansions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment758753_421742), why is the second double quote not the end of the first double quote (as shown by the syntax highlighting in your reply), but a start of a string  inside `$(...)`? Is it because the parser of bash is top-down, instead of bottom-up?

Comment: There is a lot of variation in the handling of `"${var-"foo"}"` (`echo "${-+"*"}"` is the same as `echo *` in the Bourne or Korn shell for instance) and [the behaviour will be made clearly unspecified in the next version of the standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=221#c399). See also discussion at https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg00167.html

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps looking at the two examples with `printf` (instead of `echo`) will help:

```
$ printf '<%s> ' "(echo " * ")"; echo
<(echo > <test.txt> <ppcg.sh> <file1> <file2> <file3> <)>
```

It prints `(echo`  (the first word, including a trailing space), some files, and the closing word `)`.
The parenthesis is just part of the quoted string `(echo` .
The asterisk (now unquoted, as the two double quotes are paired) is expanded as a glob to a list of matching files.
And then, the closing parenthesis.

However, your second command works as follows:

```
$ printf '<%s> ' "$(echo " * ")" ; echo
< * >
```

The `$` starts a command substitution. That starts a-fresh the quoting.
The asterisk is quoted `" * "` and that is what the command (here it is a command and not a quoted string) `echo` outputs. Finally, `printf` re-formats the `*` and prints it as `< * >`.