# Should I double quote these parameter expansions?

Tags: bash

shellcheck gives me the following warning:

```
In myscript line 38:
        echo -e "blah/blah\n$(cat ${tmpdir}/${filename}.jpdf)" > "$tmpdir"/"$filename".jpdf
                                            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

The command in question is intended to insert a line at the beginning of a file `${tmpdir}/${filename}.jpdf`.

Does the warning by shellcheck make sense? Why?

I have already double quote the entire argument to `echo -e`, and should I further double quote `${tmpdir}` and `${filename}`?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How are double quotation marks in `bash` matched (paired)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421729/how-are-double-quotation-marks-in-bash-matched-paired)

Comment: Note that `$(...)` introduces a subshell and in that subshell variables still need to be quoted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes if you want to avoid splitting&globbing like this:

```
echo -e "blah/blah\n$(cat "${tmpdir}/${filename}.jpdf")" > "$tmpdir/$filename.jpdf"
```

Just internal double quotes. I mean, inside the `$(…)` which is already double quoted on the outside `"$(…)"`

Comment: The syntax highlight of UL SE seems buggy in this case.

Comment: Then how can `$(cat ${tmpdir}/${filename}.jpdf)` be expanded in your change?

Comment: @Tim Have you tried it? The quoting start a fresh inside `$(…)`. I seem to be failing to understand your comment, care to elaborate?

Comment: In `"blah/blah\n$(cat "${tmpdir}/${filename}.jpdf")"`, why is the second double quote not the end of the first double quote (as shown by the syntax highlighting in your reply), but a start of a string  inside `$(...)`?

Comment: @Tim [Please read and **try**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421747/265604), in short, the quoting starts again inside a `$(…)`.