# Is there any sh code that is not syntactically valid bash code?

Tags: bash, shell-script, posix

Is there any `sh` code that is not syntactically valid bash code (won't barf on syntax)?

I am thinking of overwriting `sh` with `bash` for certain commands.

Comment: How do you define "valid" for your purposes?

Comment: well I guess there is sourceable and runnable, maybe those are 2 different things

Comment: I guess by valid I meant syntactically valid, so it won't barf on syntax

Comment: meaning bash won't ever barf when it sees sh syntax

Comment: Different tokenizing? e.g. `((` comes to mind.

Comment: For some distros `/usr/bin/sh` is just a sym-link to `/usr/bin/bash` (I'm using CentOS 7.3 and it is). You should check to see if `sh` is really `bash` for your distro.

Comment: @Centimane that is interesting maybe I can use /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh for some stuff

Comment: A few years ago, my whole project broke when something was "upgraded" in bash. I had to change all my shebang lines from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`. Then everything worked again, so you do really have to be careful. It may have happened when they started using dash instead of bash for  sh.

Comment: @Joe, that's the opposite of what the OP is asking for -- you had bash code that was mislabeled as being sh code but wasn't. The OP is asking if they can have (actual, not mislabeled) *sh* code that breaks when it runs with bash, not if they can have bash code that breaks when it runs with sh (which is obvious -- if bash extensions didn't have any effect on available language features, they wouldn't be extensions).

Comment: @charlesduffy Not exactly. My code was honestly intended to be sh code  and had worked as such for years.  There well may have been bashisms in it, but I was unawaware of any issues. My code certainly wasn't "mislabeled."

Comment: @Joe, ...if you still have that code, you might paste it into http://shellcheck.net/ with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang; it won't catch every bashism, but it at least finds a good number of them. And yes, I know you *intended* your code to be compatible with `/bin/sh`, but there's practical evidence that it wasn't :)

Comment: Funny that OP leads to a point where accepting only 1 answer would generally be wrong

Answer (score 48):

Here is some code that *does something different* in POSIX sh and Bash:

```
hello &> world
```

Whether that is "invalid" for you I don't know.

In Bash, it [redirects both standard output and standard error](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) from `hello` into the file `world`. In POSIX `sh`, it runs `hello` in the background and then makes an empty redirection into `world`, truncating it (i.e. it's treated as `& >`).

There are plenty of other cases where Bash extensions will do their thing when run under `bash`, and would have different effects in a pure POSIX `sh`. For example, [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) is another, and it too operates the same under Bash's POSIX mode and not.

---

As far as static syntax errors go, Bash has both reserved words (like `[[` and `time`) not specified by POSIX, such that `[[ x` is valid POSIX shell code but a Bash syntax error, and a history of various [POSIX incompatibility bugs that may result in syntax errors, such as the one from this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340923/what-does-posix-require-for-quoted-here-documents-inside-command-substitution):

```
x=$(cat <<'EOF'
`
EOF
)
bash: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Syntax-errors-only is a pretty dangerous definition of "invalid" for any circumstance where it matters, but there it is.

Comment: Note that while brace expansion currently makes bash (and zsh, pdksh, ksh93) non-compliant, [POSIX is working at adding provision in the specification to allow brace expansion](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1193) (and `{fd}>file` a similar issue), so that bash can be conformant again (brace expansion would stay unspecified, but compliant scripts would need to do `echo "{a,b}"` is they want `{a,b}` to  be output). See [discussion that started it](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02173.html)

Comment: Also relevant to this Q&A: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1191#c3983

Comment: Would someone writing a script in POSIX sh ever write a command like this? The OP is going from sh to bash, and from my understanding this seems like it would be more of a problem going in the other direction?

Comment: @Rich: Sure. I don't use any systems where `/bin/sh` is bash, so if I weren't actively aware of this bashism, writing a command line this could easily happen. The spacing in the  answer makes it look unlikely, but `hello&>world` is less far-fetched.

Comment: I thought the OP was clear that the example is asking for a case where valid POSIX sh syntax is not also valid bash syntax. "Behaves differently" != "invalid syntax".

Comment: The OP was very much not clear on what "valid" meant, and I suspect still isn't really.

Comment: @Rich Most of them are pretty unlikely, which is why Bash was able to repurpose the syntax like that. The question is whether there is *any* code that isn't "valid", though, and there is on all fronts (behaviourally by design, syntactically by design, and bugs). You could write something in the POSIX dialect and it wouldn't work in Bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think the clarification about "not barfing on syntax" was added after this answer was initially written. In any case, the non-syntactic differences can still cause problems regarding the actual job the script is doing, so it's not like they're completely ignorable.

Comment: I actually saw a [bug due to the `&>` difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714983/shell-script-does-not-give-expected-output-in-ubuntu) just last month!

Answer (score 16):

A short example:

```
time()(:)
```

`time` in Bash is a reserved word, and behaves differently from the `time` program. It's quite likely you'll break some practical scripts trying to parse the result of `time` by using bash. But technically it is not a syntax error. Redefining `time` as a function would be rare but causes a syntax error as this question specifies.

A shorter example:

```
a():
```

Valid in `dash`, but not POSIX compliant.

Comment: More generally, any word that is a nonstandard keyword or a builtin command in Bash will cause the same effect. In addition to `time`, there's stuff like `declare`, `function`, `select`, and `coproc`. Though some of those are explicitly marked as unspecified in the standard ([keywords](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04) and [builtins/utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01)), but I can't see e.g. `time` or `coproc` in the list. And using `--posix` doesn't seem to help.