# Using a here-doc with trailing backslashes inside a process substitution in bash

Tags: bash, escape-characters, here-document, process-substitution

This:

```
cat <<EOF
one
two
three
EOF
```

Prints:

```
one
two
three
```

And this:

```
cat <<EOF
one \\
two \\
three
EOF
```

Prints:

```
one \
two \
three
```

But while this:

```
cat <(
cat <<EOF
one
two
three
EOF
)
```

Prints:

```
one
two
three
```

This:

```
cat <(
cat <<EOF
one \\
two \\
three
EOF
)
```

Prints:

```
one \two \three
```

What's going on? Why are the newlines disappearing in this situation?

Comment: Similar to [What does POSIX require for quoted here documents inside command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340923/22142) (probably the same bug or similar...)

Comment: That has been solved in bash 5.0.