# Precedence of Pipe (|) and logical and (&&) in bash

Tags: bash

The classic scenario with Operator Precedence, you have a line like :

```
(cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot* | head -n 5)
```

And you don't know if it's parsed `((A && B) | C)` or `(A && B | C)`...

The *almost official documentation* found [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html) doesn't list the pipe in the list so I cannot simply check in the table.

Furthermore in bash, `(` is not only for changing the order of operations but *creates a subshell*, so I'm not 100% sure this lines is the equivalent of the previous line :

```
((cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot*) | head -n 5)
```

More generally, how to know the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of a bash line? In python I have a function that gives me the tree so that I can easily double check the order of operation.

Comment: It might help to know that `|` is just a connector that fits the LHS stdout to the RHS stdin.  So if the `cd` command in your example fails, it would send no output to `head`, but `head` would in fact still `execute`, parse the nothing, and return no output.

Comment: See also [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/315749)

Comment: `bash` is using a yacc [parser](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?h=bash-5.0-testing) not some ad-hoc thing; if you run that through `yacc -v` it will give you in `y.output` a nice grammar that shows that `&&` and `||` combine lists, and lists are eventually made up of pipelines (and not the reverse); **tl;dr;** `A && B | C` is the same as `A && { B | C; }`, as expected. Don't assume any order of execution between `B` and `C`; the commands in a pipeline are run in *parallel*.

Comment: Notice that that "almost official documentation" you point to is completely irrelevant, as it's about the operators used inside `[...]` tests and `$((...))` arithmetic evaluations; in particular, `||` and `&&` as used with commands list in the shell language have the **same precedence**, unlike the respective operators in `C` or in arithmetic evaluation (where `&&` binds more tightly than `||`).

Comment: @mosvy, that document doesn't even say what context the table applies in, so it seems less than useful in that sense, too...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot* | head -n 5
```

This is equivalent to

```
cd ~/screenshots && { ls screenshot* | head -n 5 ; }
```

(the [braces group commands together without a subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)). The precedence of `|` is thus higher (binds tighter) than `&&` and `||`. That is,

```
A && B | C
```

and

```
A || B | C
```

always mean that **only B's output is to be given to C**. You can use `(...)` or `{ ... ; }` to join commands together as a single entity for disambiguation if necessary:

```
{ A && B ; } | C
A && { B | C ; } # This is the default, but you might sometimes want to be explicit
```

---

You can test this out using some different commands. If you run

```
echo hello && echo world | tr a-z A-Z
```

then you'll get

```
hello
WORLD
```

back: [`tr a-z A-Z` upper-cases its input](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), and you can see that only `echo world` was piped into it, while `echo hello` went through on its own.

---

This *is* defined in the [shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), although not terribly clearly: the `and_or` production (for `&&`/`||`) is defined to have a a `pipeline` in its body, while `pipeline` just contains `command`, which *doesn't* contain `and_or` - only the `complete_command` production can reach `and_or`, and it only exists at the top level and inside the bodies of structural constructs like functions and loops.

You can manually apply that grammar to get a parse tree for a command, but Bash doesn't provide anything itself. I don't know of any shell that does beyond what's used for their own parsing.

The shell grammar has a lot of special cases defined only semi-formally and it can be quite a mission to get right. Even Bash itself [has sometimes gotten it wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340923/73093), so the practicalities and the ideal may be different.

There are external parsers that attempt to match the syntax and produce a tree, and of those I will broadly recommend [Morbig](https://github.com/colis-anr/morbig), which attempts to be the most reliable.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR**: list separators such as `;`. `&`, `&&`, and `||` decide the parsing order.

The [bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) tells us:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more **pipelines** separated by
>   the && and || control operators, respectively.

Or how [Bash Hacker's wiki](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar) succinctly put it

```
<PIPELINE1> && <PIPELINE2>
```

Thus, in `cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot* | head -n 5`  there is one pipeline - `ls screenshot* | head -n 5` and one simple command `cd ~/screenshots/`. Note that according to the manual

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e.,
>          in a subshell).

On the other hand, `(cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot*) | head -n 5` is different - you have one pipeline: on the left there is subshell and on the right you have `head -n 5`. In this case, using OP's notation it would be `(A && B) | C`

---

Let's take another example:

```
$ echo foo | false &&  echo 123 | tr 2 5
$
```

Here we have one list `<pipeline1> && <pipeline2>`. Since we know that exit status of pipeline is the same as of the last command and `false` returns negative status aka fail, `&&` won't execute right hand side.

```
$ echo foo | true &&  echo 123 | tr 2 5
153
```

Here the left pipeline has success exit status, so right pipeline is executed and we see its output.

---

Note that shell grammar doesn't imply actual execution order. To quote one of [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/85039):

> Piped commands run concurrently. When you run ps | grep …, it's the luck of the draw (or a matter of details of the workings of the shell combined with scheduler fine-tuning deep in the bowels of the kernel) as to whether ps or grep starts first, and in any case they continue to execute concurrently.

And from bash manual:

> AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.

Based on that in `cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot* | head -n 5` the `cd ~/screenshots/` would be executed first, `ls screenshot* | head -n 5` if previous command succeeds, but `head -n 5` may be a first process spawned rather than `ls` since they are in a pipeline.

Comment: I don't see where the question asks anything about what order things are spawned.

Comment: _"there is no precedence of which one spawns first, `cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot*` or `head -n 5`"_ Well, yes, that's the case with `((cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot*) | head -n 5)`. But it doesn't say anything about the ambiguous case `cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot* | head -n 5` which seems to be the point of the question (with or without surrounding parenthesis).

Comment: @ilkkachu  Right, but the following sentences touch on that. `cd ~/screenshots/ && ls screenshot* ` would have to be processed first because `&&` lists is higher on the order of precedence (based on l0b0's answer, at least).    Where do you think I should improve the answer ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, well, given that the question has both `(cd && ls | head)` and `((cd && ls) | head)`, it might be good to be explicit about which one you mean.

Comment: @ilkkachu OK, I'm gonna delete this for now, and edit it in the meantime

Comment: @ilkkachu Answer updated, let me know if anything needs fixing

Comment: @MichaelHomer I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's where it's specified in `bash(1)`:

```
SHELL GRAMMAR
[...]
   Pipelines
       A  pipeline  is  a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of
       the control operators | or |&.
[...]
   Lists
       A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one  of  the
       operators ;, &, &&, or ||, and optionally terminated by one of ;, &, or
       <newline>.
```

So, `&&` separates pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

You could just try `echo hello && echo world | less`. You will see that `|` has higher precedence (A pipeline of commands is a command). There for your 2nd example is **NOT** the same. However because `cd` has no output, you will see no difference, ether way.